# How to use the same bean defined in multiple applicationContext.xml files?

Tags: spring

I have two Spring projects: a client and server application. I would like to create a third integration test project. However my tests fail with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'meterRegistry' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot register bean definition [Generic bean: class [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]] for bean 'meterRegistry': There is already [Generic bean: class [io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]] bound.
```

Each of the applications defines their own (identical) meterRegistry bean in their respective applicationContext.xml files.

Is there any way of telling Spring that both applications can share the meterRegistry bean?

Comment: Create third file and `<import/>` it in both (server an client) ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<import>` field in the `applicationContext.xml` :

How to use ?

For example :

applicationContextClient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id = "example" class="com.test.Example"/>

</beans>
```

applicationContextServer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

         <import resource="applicationContextClient.xml" />

         <bean id="Example2" class="com.test.Example2">
           <property name="example" ref="example"/>
         </bean> 

</beans>
```

Comment: @spierepf Is this answer helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I would up adding an `application.properties` file to the integration test project that contained:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```